# Assistance with Copy & Paste VB System

Tags: vb.net

The system is meant to work so that whenever the `gta_sa` process stops running, it copies the file selected when browsing cmdFile to cmdStorage's location. Problem I have right now is that it doesn't store the new file in .txt, but rather just as .file. It's openable, but not as default.

Also, I wasn't sure how to do the detection on when gtasa process was recently closed so I had to use if the process is active. I'd really appreciate it for some help, thanks.**

EDIT: Maybe it needs to use a timer? Not sure, thanks again.

```
Imports System.Diagnostics 
Imports System Imports System.ComponentModel 

Public Class frmChatLog
    Dim ofdDone
    Dim fldDone
    Dim Completed

    Private Sub cmdStorage_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStorage.Click
        Using fld As New FolderBrowserDialog()
            If fld.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("Selected " & fld.SelectedPath)
                fldDone = fld.SelectedPath
                cmdStorage.Enabled = False
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdFile_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdFile.Click
        Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog()
            If ofd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                MessageBox.Show("Selected " & ofd.FileName)
                ofdDone = ofd.FileName
                cmdFile.Enabled = False
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdStart_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click
        If cmdFile.Enabled = False And cmdStorage.Enabled = False Then
            Do Until Process.GetProcessesByName("gta_sa").Count > 0
                If Process.GetProcessesByName("gta_sa").Count > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Game is on")

                Else
                    System.IO.File.Move(ofdDone, fldDone & "\" & Today.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss"))
                    Completed = fldDone & "\" & Today.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss")
                    Completed.ChangeExtension(".txt")
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop

        End If
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: Completed is declared without any type (bad thing), populated as a string, but you use a method not supported by the string type. You haven't included any code where Completed is used. What type is this variable expected to have? String, Path, etc.

Comment: That was my attempt at fixing it, it didn't work. I don't know whether to work off a timer now or just off the detection I have. What the aim is to, the game creates a log everytime you play, and this program is meant to copy it, date it and place it elsewhere for safekeeping.

Comment: Please, understand what I am asking. I am asking for a sample where Completed is used. You are populating it but you are not showing where you use its value; without knowing where it is used (and thus its type), I cannot help.

Comment: `Dim Completed` implies some sort of simple variable; `Completed = fldDone & ...` confirms it as string. `Completed.ChangeExtension(".txt")` doesnt make sense.  From what we can see that should not even compile - it is a string (?) not a `IO.Path` object

Answer (score 0):

> Problem I have right now is that it doesn't store the new file in .txt, but rather just as .file.

To fix that, change this line near the bottom of your code:

```
System.IO.File.Move(ofdDone, fldDone & "\" & Today.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss"))
```

to this:

```
File.Move(ofdDone, Path.Combine(fldDone, Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss") & ".txt"))
```

Then get rid of any line that mentions your `Completed` variable. You may also need to add an `Imports System.IO` to the top of the file.